# ES6 Map in Flowtype

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

What is the **appropriate way** to deal with [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) `Map` objects in [flowtype](/questions/tagged/flowtype)?

```
const animals:Map<id, Animal> = new Map();

function feedAnimal(cageNumber:number) {
    const animal:Animal = animals.get(cageNumber);

    ...
}
```

Error

```
const animal:Animal = animals.get(cageNumber);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ call of method `get`

const animal:Animal = animals.get(cageNumber);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ undefined. This type is incompatible with
const animal:Animal = animals.get(cageNumber);
                      ^^^^^^^ Animal
```

[Flowtype Map declaration](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/ff07cd569eaa06dad72ba72ae2df37cf2eb14933/lib/core.js#L447-L462)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Type of `animals.get(cageNumber)` is `?Animal`, not `Animal`. You need to check that it's not undefined:

```
function feedAnimal(cageNumber:number) {
  const animal = animals.get(cageNumber);

  if (!animal) {
    return;
  } 
  // ...
}
```

Comment: If the only goal is to never have `void`, then you can also use `if (animals.has(cageNumber))` which is more readable (and probably faster since you don't allocate things to remove them right after). 

But I have no idea how to return something with the correct type, ie., `Animal`. According to Flow your solution and mine  both return types are `void | Animal`. This makes sense because you probably don't want Flow to guess what your code does, therefore the return type is equal to `animal`'s type. 

If anyone has a solution to this i'm interested.

Comment: @ChristianG. There's no allocation in this answer. All what happens is an assignment to the reference `animal`. In theory, `if (animals.has(cageNumber)) { const animal: Animal = animals.get(cageNumber); ...}` could work, but it'd require Flow to know how `has` and `get` are related. This is possible, but improbable as `Map` isn't used very often. Anyway, I'd bet that using both `has` and `get` is slower than using `get` and then testing, as it requires two accesses - unless the JIT has a corresponding optimization (which I doubt because of `Map` not being used very often).